# Losing pointer reference to structure member ? (in c)

Tags: c, pointers, memory, nested, function-pointers

I am making a little project just for fun about OO in C.
The problem I am encountering is fairly odd to me. The program below is the entire thing.

When compiled and ran, all the 'methods' work properly... up until after it hits the first 'puts'. At this point, the 'methods' have lost the reference to 'self' at this point.

I'm not sure why it works up until then, but not after. It is worth noting that executing the 'constructor' again before the second 'puts' will make it work. The 'if' chains clearly show that the methods work because they properly set the new strings.

I do realize this would be fixed by simply passing the 'object's' address via parameters to the 'methods', but that's kind of the point of the post, I would like to find a neat way to do it without doing so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//-----class_a--------------------------------------------------------------//
typedef struct{
    char*   string;
    char*   (*get_string)();
    char*   (*set_string)(char*);
} class_a;

void constructor_class_a(class_a *self, char* string){

    self->string            = string;

    char* get_string(){
        return self->string;
    } self->get_string      = get_string;

    char* set_string(char* new_string){
        return self->string = new_string;
    } self->set_string      = set_string;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int main(){
    class_a object_a;
    constructor_class_a(&object_a, "default string");

    printf("string: %s\n", object_a.get_string());
    if (object_a.get_string()=="default string"){
        object_a.set_string("temporary string");
        if (object_a.get_string()=="temporary string"){
            object_a.set_string("final string");
            if (object_a.get_string()=="final string"){
                printf("string: %s\n", object_a.get_string());
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s", object_a.get_string());
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried doing this to no avail (including a int init member to the 'class'):

```
char* get_string(){
    static class_a *self2 = {0};
    if (!self2->inti){
        *self2 = *self;
        self2->init = 1;
    }
    return self2->string;
} self->get_string      = get_string;
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what the intent is behind declaring functions inside a function. Those should be declared independently. You could assign function pointers to them to your struct, but that's really quite pointless unless you're trying to implement some kind of function dispatch table (vtable) here.

Comment: The way object-oriented C usually works is you have a function of the form `class_a_get_string(class_a* self)` where `self` is explicitly passed in. Maybe I'm missing out on something C can do for you here, but C doesn't really have a "lambda" or "closure" type feature as do other languages. A function call cannot have implied context, only explicit arguments. You might be able to do something diabolical (and extremely not thread-safe) with a global variable if your goal was to bludgeon C into the form you're targeting.

Comment: It's worth noting that clang flat-out refuses to compile this, much as I would have expected, with errors like "function definition is not allowed here" and "use of undeclared identifier 'get_string'". This doesn't look like something C can do without a whole lot of exceptionally creative thinking and/or some serious `#define` magic.

Comment: There is no definite point to this, only having fun. As I mentioned, it does work, 'self' is known to the 'methods' until I assume the scope is left? not sure what triggers the loss of reference when. I won't lie, I'm quite new to c, I'm just having fun and seeing the limitations of the language and how you can use them creatively :)  Also, this compiles fine with MinGW @tadman

Comment: Had you looked at the assembly code? I think compiler just inlines that with wrong addresses or so.

Comment: The widely used OOP library is _Glib_. You may look how it's done there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to use nested functions, which are not part of the C language but a GCC extension, but using them incorrectly. Their lifetimes end at the end of the block they're nested in, and any use of a function pointer to them after their lifetime ends has undefined behavior.

Even if this did work, it would be an awful idea, since the ability to have pointers to nested functions necessarily depends on having an executable stack, which is deprecated because it makes most kinds of vulnerabilities trivial to exploit. This is among the many reasons that clang and other compilers refuse to copy this GCC feature and why it's essentially dead.